# How to store a List<String> from spring JPA to text[] array in database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to write an Java- Array List into postgres database.　But i am not able to DO, i don't get error as well. I am trying to post data

```
"skill":["java,dotnet"]
```

using postman tool but on Post nothing happens and i don't see any data in db.I also don't get any error in my console.please help me out on this i m wondering how to do this

I am able to read Array data from database but cannot write

```
    /*
     * Spring Entity:
     */
    @Column(name="skill" , columnDefinition = "text[]")
    @Convert(converter =ListToStringConverter.class)
        private List<String> skill=new ArrayList<>();       
        ublic List<String> getSkill() {
            return skill;
        }
        public void setSkill(List<String> skill) {
            this.skill= skill;
        }

    @Converter
    public class ListToStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> { 

        @Override
        public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> attribute) {
            if (attribute == null || attribute.isEmpty()) {
                return "";
            }
            return StringUtils.join(attribute, ",");
        }

        @Override
        public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
            if (dbData == null || dbData.trim().length() == 0) {
                return new ArrayList<String>();
            }

            String[] data = dbData.split(",");
            return Arrays.asList(data);
        }
    }



Controller Code:
```

This is my Controller code to create a object in database and i use a interface service that is call from controller to Save to db-Postgres which is a JPA repo

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/reqCreate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Requirement> addRequirement(@RequestBody Requirement requirement) {
        reqService.save(requirement);               
        return new ResponseEntity<Requirement>(requirement, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

Service:
    public void save(Requirement r) {           
        reqRepo.save(r);
    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! You showed us how you handle data conversion between `List` and `String`. But how do you actually access the database? Please edit your question and add that code to it. Do you have any error messages or exceptions?

Comment: Does it work without `columnDefinition = "text[]"`?

Comment: care to say whether your TABLE schema was created with a column of type `text[]` ?

Comment: Hi Lupz i get the follwoing error code :ERROR: column "skill" is of type text[] but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: @Carrie were you able to find a solution for this. I am facing the same issue and not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 4):

The `columnDefinition` seems to be wrong.

You want to convert Collection into String, but you still declare column of array type.

Replace `"text[]"` with `"text"` and check if it works?

Comment: Tough luck i am still not able to save to Database:-( i can only read this in my console###[INFO] 2017-07-08 09:26:17:441 [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
###[INFO] 2017-07-08 09:26:17:502 [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 60 ms

Comment: Make sure you let hibernate recreate the schema with new column definition.